# Laravel - Use Middleware for restrict the user blocked profile?

Tags: laravel, block, middleware, profile

I am working on a project in Laravel, it's a scratch of a social network. I have a important question. I have a controller with the profile of the user, there first of all i look if the user exists, if not exists it gets a 404, if exists get the data and the controller sends it to the view.

But now I was thinking that I can do a Blocking System between users. I created the table with N:n, were it's the user id who blocked and the user id of the destiny.

I made a Middleware to check if the users is blocked. But this middleware is executed on the route, and this means is executed before check if the user exists. It doesnt make me any problem. It's all working but my question is: This the best solution? It's better use a policy?

**User Model**

```
public function usersBlockedI()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'u_blocks', 'u_from', 'u_to');
}
```

- u_blocks is the name of the table.
- u_from is the name of the user who made the block.
- u_to the user who received the block.

**User Controller:**

```
public function showProfile($username)
{

    $profileUser = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    if ($profileUser == null) { 
        return abort(404);     
    } else {
        $profileUser['dataUser'] = dataUser::where('u_id', $profileUser['id'])->first();
        return view('user.profile', compact('profileUser'));
    }
}
```

**Block Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()) {
        $usernameProfile = $request->route('username');;
        $ActualuserID = auth()->user()->id;
        $checkIfBlocked = User::where('username', $usernameProfile)->first()->usersBlockedI->where('id', $ActualuserID);
        if (!sizeof($checkIfBlocked) == 0) {
            abort(404);
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'blocked'], function () {
Route::get('/{username}', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('showProfile');
```

});

Comment: Looks alright to me. One improvement I'd do is make a method in User model to check so it looks tidier for the long `$checkIfBlocked`.

Comment: it looks great , if only you would like to check if the destiny user is blocked by the authenticated user, like facebook, u cant see the user that you previously blocked, but can't get simpler than this.

Comment: Yeah! This is the point, but in some settings the user would be able to unblock the user that he blocked before. The same as facebook! ;)